# GridView row not inflating

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-arrayadapter, android-gridview

I have a simple `GridView` with custom Adapter in my layouts. My code is as follows:

**CircleActivity.java:**

```
public class CircleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_circle);

        List<Integer> listColors = new ArrayList<>();
        listColors.add(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        listColors.add(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        listColors.add(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));

        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_colors);
        CircleAdapter adapter = new CircleAdapter(this,listColors);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**activity_circle.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <GridView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid_colors"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**CircleAdapter.java:**

```
public class CircleAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private Context context;
private List<Integer> listColor;

public CircleAdapter(Context context, List<Integer> listColor) {
    this.listColor = listColor;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listColor.size();
}

@Override
public Integer getItem(int position) {
    return listColor.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_grid,parent,false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.customCircleView.setFillColor(listColor.get(position));
    holder.customCircleView.setCircleRadius(100);
    return convertView;
}


static class ViewHolder{
    private CustomCircleView customCircleView;
    public ViewHolder(View row){
        customCircleView = (CustomCircleView) row.findViewById(R.id.custom_circle_view);
    }
  }
}
```

**row_grid.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.droidexperiments.gridexpand.CustomCircleView
        android:id="@+id/custom_circle_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        custom:fill_color="@color/colorPrimary"
        custom:circle_radius="50"
        android:padding="25dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**CircleView.java:**

```
public class CustomCircleView extends View {
private int circleRadius = 20;
private int fillColor = Color.BLACK;


public CustomCircleView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomCircleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context, attrs);
}

public CustomCircleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context, attrs);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public CustomCircleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    init(context, attrs);
}

private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.CustomCircle);
    circleRadius = typedArray.getInteger(R.styleable.CustomCircle_circle_radius,20);
    fillColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.CustomCircle_fill_color, Color.BLACK);
    typedArray.recycle();
}

public int getCircleRadius() {
    return circleRadius;
}

public void setCircleRadius(int circleRadius) {
    this.circleRadius = circleRadius;
}

public int getFillColor() {
    return fillColor;
}

public void setFillColor(int fillColor) {
    this.fillColor = fillColor;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(fillColor);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()/2,canvas.getHeight()/2,circleRadius,paint);
}
```

}

**attrts.xml:**

```
   <declare-styleable name="CustomCircle">
        <attr name="fill_color" format="reference|color"/>
        <attr name="circle_radius" format="integer"/>
    </declare-styleable>
```

The issue is that screen remains blank and no row is inflated/showing in GridView.

I have checked everything. There is not any issue in GridView or the layout of  grid row or in `CustomCircleView`. If I change `adapter` to simple `ArrayAdapter`, it works fine. So, there must be issue with my adapter:

I double checked `getView()` in adapter;

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_grid,parent,false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.customCircleView.setFillColor(listColor.get(position));
        holder.customCircleView.setCircleRadius(100);
        return convertView;
    }
```

but couldn't identify why it shows blank. can anyone help me please?

Comment: can you try `customCircleView` as `public` instead of `private` ?

Comment: I tried and if there is an issue , shouldn't the compiler raise issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you implement a custom view, it is essential that you implement `onMeasure`. This method will tell the Android framework what size your view should be. Since you didn't specify this for `CustomCircleView` and used `wrap_content` in your layout, it had size zero. Therefore, all the elements of the `GridView` were invisible, making it look like the adapter was not working. I made a simple example implementation of `onMeasure` that solves your problem (just add this method in `CustomCircleView`):

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int size = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(2 * this.circleRadius, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    setMeasuredDimension(size, size);
}
```

The documentation advises that `size` stays within the given parameters (`widthMeasureSpec` and `heightMeasureSpec`). I have not included that restriction here, you can determine yourself what you want to do in that case.
You can find more information about this in the [guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#custom) on creating custom components. Specific information about `onMeasure` can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure%28int,%20int%29).